# Show items in dropdownlist that is not equal to the selected item in other dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Example I have 5 `DropDownList` with values

```
red, orange, yellow, green, blue
```

if `DropDownList1` select red

The choices for `DropDownList2-5` will be

```
orange, yellow, green, blue
```

if `DropDownList2` select `yellow`

The choices for `DropDownList3-5` will be

```
orange, green, blue
```

---

Here is the code I found in the internet, this is only for 3 `DropDownList` but what I need is for 5 `DropDownList`. I can't expand the code for 5 `DropDownList`

**VB**

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private bFlag As Boolean = True

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillddlLocations()
    End If
End Sub

'Properties to store selected value in ViewState

Protected Property MemberID1Selection() As String
    Get
        If ViewState("MemberID1Selection") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return ViewState("MemberID1Selection").ToString()
        End If
        Return ""
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("MemberID1Selection") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Property MemberID2Selection() As String
    Get
        If ViewState("MemberID2Selection") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return ViewState("MemberID2Selection").ToString()
        End If
        Return ""
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("MemberID2Selection") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Property MemberID3Selection() As String
    Get
        If ViewState("MemberID3Selection") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return ViewState("MemberID3Selection").ToString()
        End If
        Return ""
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("MemberID3Selection") = value
    End Set
End Property


Protected Sub FillddlLocations()
    FillDropdown(companyID1)
    FillDropdown(companyID2)
    FillDropdown(companyID3)

    companyID1.Visible = True
    companyID2.Visible = True
    companyID3.Visible = True

End Sub

Protected Sub FillDropdown(ddl As DropDownList)

    Using connAdd = New SqlConnection("Data Source = MENDOZAABBY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = ThesisDatabase; Integrated Security= True")
        connAdd.Open()

        Dim sql = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Company Where College = 'CCS'"
        Using cmdAdd = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd)
            Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
            cmdAdd.Fill(ds2)


            ddl.Items.Clear()
            ddl.DataSource = ds2
            ddl.DataTextField = "CompanyName"
            ddl.DataValueField = "CompanyName"
            ddl.DataBind()
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select a Company", ""))

            ddl.SelectedIndex = 0

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Protected Sub IndexChanged(ddlChanged As DropDownList, ddlToFilter1 As DropDownList, ddlToFilter2 As DropDownList)
    Dim removeValue1 As String = If(ddlChanged Is companyID1, MemberID1Selection, (If(ddlChanged Is companyID2, MemberID2Selection, MemberID3Selection)))
    Dim selValue2 As String = If(ddlChanged Is companyID1, MemberID2Selection, (If(ddlChanged Is companyID2, MemberID1Selection, MemberID1Selection)))
    Dim selValue3 As String = If(ddlChanged Is companyID1, MemberID3Selection, (If(ddlChanged Is companyID2, MemberID3Selection, MemberID2Selection)))

    bFlag = False
    'Prevent fireing the code again while changing the index
    If removeValue1 <> "" Then
        Dim item1 As ListItem = ddlToFilter1.Items.FindByValue(removeValue1)
        ddlToFilter1.Items.Remove(item1)
        Dim item2 As ListItem = ddlToFilter2.Items.FindByValue(removeValue1)
        ddlToFilter2.Items.Remove(item2)

    End If

    If selValue3 <> "" Then
        Dim item3 As ListItem = ddlToFilter1.Items.FindByValue(selValue3)
        ddlToFilter1.Items.Remove(item3)
    End If
    If selValue2 <> "" Then
        Dim item4 As ListItem = ddlToFilter2.Items.FindByValue(selValue2)
        ddlToFilter2.Items.Remove(item4)
    End If

    bFlag = False
    ddlToFilter1.SelectedIndex = ddlToFilter1.Items.IndexOf(ddlToFilter1.Items.FindByValue(selValue2))
    ddlToFilter2.SelectedIndex = ddlToFilter2.Items.IndexOf(ddlToFilter2.Items.FindByValue(selValue3))

End Sub

Protected Sub ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MemberID1Selection = companyID1.SelectedValue
    If bFlag Then
        FillDropdown(companyID2)
        FillDropdown(companyID3)
        IndexChanged(companyID1, companyID2, companyID3)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MemberID2Selection = companyID2.SelectedValue
    If bFlag Then
        FillDropdown(companyID1)
        FillDropdown(companyID3)
        IndexChanged(companyID2, companyID1, companyID3)
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MemberID3Selection = companyID3.SelectedValue
    If bFlag Then
        FillDropdown(companyID1)
        FillDropdown(companyID2)
        IndexChanged(companyID3, companyID1, companyID2)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

---

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="companyID1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="companyID2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="companyID3" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Me give you an idea, which will work. Create a matrix object. It could be an array.

```
 Items -> |  red | orange | yellow | green | 
 Controls |      |        |        |       |
    |     |      |        |        |       |
    V     |      |        |        |       |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo1   |true  | false  | true   |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo2   |true  | false  | true   |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo3   |true  |  false | true   |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo4   |true  |  true  | true   |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
```

Update:

According to this matrix your interface will have combo4 items  - All, other combos will only have red, yellow and green.

when combo3 is clicked next and, for example, yellow selected you will fill the cell "combo3/yellow" with "true" and other remaining cells under yellow - "false".

```
 Items -> |  red | orange | yellow | green | 
 Controls |      |        |        |       |
    |     |      |        |        |       |
    V     |      |        |        |       |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo1   |true  | false  | false  |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo2   |true  | false  | false  |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo3   |true  |  false |  true  |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
 combo4   |true  |  true  | false  |true   |
 _________|______|________|________|_______|
```

got the idea?

Now, develop logic that will set those "cells" to false as you click your combos.
In the beginning, all colors will be available to all controls - "true". Then you click one (any) combo. You reserve that control/color cell. Then you build your UI based on this matrix. With each click you have postback and your controls will be re-populated with available colors.

The best part - you will be able to have any number of controls or items for them. Once you run out of items or out of controls, you can't fill controls :o)

Comment: The items of the dropdownlist is from the database so I don't know how to show the items that is not selected in other dropdownlist.

Comment: It doesn't matter where Items come from, DB or any other source. Build a matrix and when selected in your combo, mark item as "Selected" or "true", while for other combos in the matrix mark same item as "can't select" or false. Then load only items, which are true to your combos. This is easy